# Add to cart button not working in product page

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

here the error (from dev tools) when clicking on the Add to Cart button :

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Changes I made (but several days before the problem appeared where activing an SSL and upgrading to Magento 1.9.3.6)

Here the code from the file addtocart.phtml:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="add-to-cart">
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
<div class="qty-wrapper">
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo 
$this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" 
class="input-text qty" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-
addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" 
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo 
$buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Check your <form> tags on the page. Make sure the form tag is closed properly and encapsulates the block that contains the addtocart phtml.

Comment: Hello could you clarify me where I should make this verify? Really thanks

Comment: Go to the product page and View Page Source. Look for your <form> and </form> tags related to adding the product to cart.  Ensure that both tags exist and that the addtocart output is between them somewhere on the page.

Comment: @DConsulting Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score -1):

" id="product-
addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" 
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">
getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

change to button type to submit

" id="product-
addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" 
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">
getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

Comment: I don't think changing the button type will make any difference. All the sites I have use type="button"